# read output from /dev/ttyUSB0

Tags: bash, shell

I am newbie in Linux, sorry if the question sounds too easy.

I have some communication with the board.
what i do first is:
enable the usb and  gsm driver and cat "/dev/ttyUSB0 &"

afterwards, I send some AT commands and automatically get replies like "OK" and so on.

What I want is to able to READ this output using bash scripts, or any other possible ways

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use screen command to read and write to the GSM. for eg. execute the command **sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0**  , it will open a new screen their you can send data and see received data.